# Add CSS pulse animation to a button without hover

Tags: wordpress, button, css-animations

I want to add an animation to my button without having to hover on it, exactly like the example here   [Add CSS shaking animation to a button without hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262508/add-css-shaking-animation-to-a-button-without-hover)

but with a differet animation, preferably pulse animation but my coding knowladge is not that much

can anybody help me with that please
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code you can try to add a pulse animation:

```
.pulse-button {
  /* Button default styles, customize them to match your button */
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3498db;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  /* Apply the pulse animation */
  animation: pulse 1s infinite;
}


@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

To break it down for you:

```
animation: pulse 1s infinite;
```

The animation property applies the pulse effect to the button. This property specifies:

- The name of the animation (pulse in this case, which matches the name
  of the @keyframes animation we'll define next).
- The duration of one cycle of the animation (1s or 1 second).
- The animation iteration count (infinite ensures the animation keeps
  repeating indefinitely).

Then the keyframe animation:

```
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

This @keyframes rule defines the actual pulse animation. The pulse animation works as follows:

- 0%: At the beginning (0% mark) of the animation, the button is at its default size (scale(1)).
- 50%: Halfway through the animation (50% mark), the button's size is increased slightly to 105% of its original size (scale(1.05)). This gives the "pulsing" effect.
- 100%: By the end (100% mark) of the animation, the button returns to its default size (scale(1)), completing one cycle.

Any button with the class .pulse-button will continuously "pulse" by slightly increasing and then returning to its original size.

Here's a [demo of the working code on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wdh45cf0/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.pulseBtn {
background:#0b63bb;
color:#fff;
border:1px solid #0b63bb;
padding:1rem 2rem;
border-radius:2rem;
font-size:1rem;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(88, 120, 243, 0.4);
-moz-animation: pulse 2s infinite;
-webkit-animation: pulse 2s infinite;
animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(88, 120, 243, 1);
    }
    70% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(88, 120, 243, 0);
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px rgba(88, 120, 243, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<button class="pulseBtn">Pulse Animation</button>
```